# Data Migration Assistant

Tags: sql, azure, database-migration

I am using Data Migration Assistant to assess compatibility issues migrating a SQL database to Azure SQL. After running for a couple of minutes, it throws an error saying "The file contains the XML node type {0}. This type is unsupported or in an unsupported location." I have successfully assessed other databases using DMA but this particular database always aborts after throwing this error.

Answer (score 0):

I decided to go ahead and migrate the database using the wizard (Deploy Database to Microsoft Azure SQL Database) from SSMS, and ran into several compatibility issues that showed as errors. The database had several triggers that were created by a third-party database tool that referred to table objects with the 3 & 4-part naming conventions which is not supported on Azure SQL. There were several other errors in addition to these but I decided to delete these triggers first and run Data Migration Assistant again. This time it ran to completion and I got compatibility report. I am not sure if it was the sheer number of issues found or something in those triggers that I deleted had caused the error.